# Amazon Simple email Service not available

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, amazon-ec2, amazon-ses

I have a website and hosted on Amazon EC2 , Country I have choosed Frankfurt. We are using the Basic Plan as we are Proof of concept level.
Now I have to Implement some email Functionalities in website , for that I want Amazon Simple email Service. But this not supported in my region.

See Screen shot

[image: Amazon]

can I use Email service in Ireland without changing the Frankfurt as website instance running country.

PS : I don't understand AWS and I am not a developer. I am trying to figure out the way to implement Email Functionalities

Thank you
Regards
Prat

Comment: Useful [Region Table](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/global-infrastructure/regional-product-services/) showing services available in each region.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use SES from another region. It might be possibly be slightly more expensive since you will incur some region-to-region bandwidth charges that might otherwise be free (not 100% sure), but I suspect unless you have a huge quantity of emails, the extra cost won't amount to much at all.

But bottom line is, yes, you can combine services from multiple regions into a single solution.

Answer (score 0):

Its not necessary to have the email service from the same region. This is due to couple of reasons,

- The added latency in selecting the closes region is not considerable when it comes to SES API invocation to send mails. In your case the performance impact, using EU (Ireland) region for email sending isn't significant.
- After the email is sent using SMTP protocol that is delivers to user's mail provider which can be in a different region. Therefore using SES in the same region won't impact the email delivery.
- You will be charged a cross regional data transfer fee for SES service used from another region. However its also not that significant if you don't have large attachments. For more details check [SES Pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/ses/pricing/).

Comment: *"You won't be charged extra for SES service used from another region"* isn't correct based on the link you provided: *"If you send email using an application hosted in EC2, you may be charged a data transfer fee."*

Comment: @Michael Does it cost for a SES API invocation when called from a different region?

Comment: All data transfer out from EC2 in one region to another AWS region is billable on the outbound side, except when the destination is CloudFront.  I don't see a documented exception for SES.  Most regions bill $0.02/GB for this traffic, some are a little higher. https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/on-demand/

Answer (score 0):

You can set up email configuration in AWS Pinpoint eu-central-1